# error by using in PDFTron:' NetworkError(`Unsupported protocol ${this._url.protocol}`'

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdftron, pdfa

I trying to convert pdf file to pdfa3 file by using PDFTron.
I added current url_path.
the my code below:

```js
 var input_url = './utils/';
            var input_filename = 'test.pdf';
            var output_filename = 'test_pdfa.pdf';
            var convert = true;
            var pwd = '';
            var exceptions;
            var max_ref_objs = 10;
            var url_input = input_url + input_filename;
            
            console.log('Converting input document: ' + input_filename);
            var pdfa = await PDFNet.PDFACompliance.createFromUrl(true, url_input, '', PDFNet.PDFACompliance.Conformance.e_Level2B, exceptions, max_ref_objs);
```

get error:
'NetworkError(`Unsupported protocol ${this._url.protocol}`)',

Does anyone know what the problem is,
And why doesn't it recognize the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to :
[here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/PDFATest/?platforms=nodejs).

Now it's working!!